# How to rotate a object using mouse in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have build the piece of code in javascript .
Now i have a object in my screen .

Here is my javascript code :

```
if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;

            var container;

            var camera, scene, renderer, mesh, directionalLight;

            var parent, meshes = [], clonemeshes = [];

            var p;

            var aloader;

            var composer, effectFocus;

            var clock = new THREE.Clock();

            init();
            animate();



            function init() {

                container = document.getElementById( 'container' );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 20, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 50000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 700, 7000 );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000104, 0.0000675 );

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );



                var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
                    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, opacity: 0.95 } ),
                    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } )
                ] );



                //

                aloader = new THREE.JSONLoader( );
                //bloader = new THREE.BinaryLoader( true );

                aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {

                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0xf00165, true );                       
                } );    
                aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {    
                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0x2a6208, true );                       
                } );    
                    aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {    
                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0x2a6208, true );                       
                } );
                        aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {    
                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0x8968CD, true );                       
                } );
                            aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {    
                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0x0e4875, true );                       
                } );
                                aloader.load( "obj/txtS.json", function( geometry ) {    
                    createMesh( geometry, scene, 40.05, -400, -450,    440, 0x1cae8a, true );                       
                });    
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                renderer.autoClear = false;
                renderer.sortObjects = false;
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );                   
                parent = new THREE.Object3D();
                scene.add( parent );  

// postprocessing

                var renderModel = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
                var effectBloom = new THREE.BloomPass( 1.5 );
                var effectFilm = new THREE.FilmPass( 0.75,0.75, 0, false );


                effectFocus = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.FocusShader );

                effectFocus.uniforms[ "screenWidth" ].value = window.innerWidth;
                effectFocus.uniforms[ "screenHeight" ].value = window.innerHeight;

                effectFocus.renderToScreen = true;

                composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );

                composer.addPass( renderModel );
                composer.addPass( effectBloom );
                composer.addPass( effectFilm );

                composer.addPass( effectFocus );

                //


                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            //

            function onWindowResize( event ) {

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );

                composer.reset();

                effectFocus.uniforms[ "screenWidth" ].value = window.innerWidth;
                effectFocus.uniforms[ "screenHeight" ].value = window.innerHeight;

            }

            //

            function createMesh( originalGeometry, scene, scale, x, y, z, color, dynamic ) {

                var i, c;

                var vertices = originalGeometry.vertices;
                var vl = vertices.length;

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                var vertices_tmp = [];

                for ( i = 0; i < vl; i ++ ) {

                    p = vertices[ i ];

                    geometry.vertices[ i ] = p.clone();
                    vertices_tmp[ i ] = [ p.x, p.y, p.z, 0, 0 ];

                }

                var clones = [

                    [  6000, 0, -4000 ],
                    [  5000, 0, 0 ],
                    [  1000, 0, 5000 ],
                    [  1000, 0, -5000 ],
                    [  4000, 0, 2000 ],
                    [ -4000, 0, 1000 ],
                    [ -5000, 0, -5000 ],

                    [ 0, 0, 0 ]

                ];

                    mesh = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size:50, color: color } ) );
                    mesh.scale.x = mesh.scale.y = mesh.scale.z = scale;

                    mesh.position.x = x;
                    mesh.position.y = y;
                    mesh.position.z = z;

                    parent.add( mesh );

                //bloader.statusDomElement.style.display = "none";
// mesh break
                meshes.push( {
                    mesh: mesh, vertices: geometry.vertices, vertices_tmp: vertices_tmp, vl: vl,
                    down: 0, up: 0, direction: 0, speed: 40, delay: Math.floor( 00 - 00 * Math.random() ),
                    //started: false, start: Math.floor( 100 + 200 * Math.random() ),
                    dynamic: dynamic
                } );

            }


            var j, jl, cm, data, vertices, vertices_tmp, vl, d, vt;

            function animate () {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }



            function render () {

                delta = 10 * clock.getDelta();

                delta = delta < 2 ? delta : 2;


                for( j = 0, jl = meshes.length; j < jl; j ++ ) {

                    data = meshes[ j ];
                    mesh = data.mesh;
                    vertices = data.vertices;
                    vertices_tmp = data.vertices_tmp;
                    vl = data.vl;

                    if ( ! data.dynamic ) continue;

                    if ( data.start > 0 ) {

                        data.start -= 1;

                    } else {

                        if ( !data.started ) {

                            data.direction = -1;
                            data.started = true;

                        }

                    }

                    for ( i = 0; i < vl; i ++ ) {

                        p = vertices[ i ];
                        vt = vertices_tmp[ i ];

                        // falling down

                        if ( data.direction < 0 ) {

                            if ( p.y > 0 ) {

                                p.x += 1.5 * ( 0.50 - Math.random() ) * data.speed * delta;
                                p.y += 3.0 * ( 0.25 - Math.random() ) * data.speed * delta;
                                p.z += 1.5 * ( 0.50 - Math.random() ) * data.speed * delta;

                            } else {

                                if ( ! vt[ 3 ] ) {

                                    vt[ 3 ] = 1;
                                    data.down += 1;

                                }

                            }

                        }

                        // rising up

                        if ( data.direction > 0 ) {


                            d = Math.abs( p.x - vt[ 0 ] ) + Math.abs( p.y - vt[ 1 ] ) + Math.abs( p.z - vt[ 2 ] );

                            if ( d > 1 ) {

                                p.x += - ( p.x - vt[ 0 ] ) / d * data.speed * delta * ( 0.85 - Math.random() );
                                p.y += - ( p.y - vt[ 1 ] ) / d * data.speed * delta * ( 1 + Math.random() );
                                p.z += - ( p.z - vt[ 2 ] ) / d * data.speed * delta * ( 0.85 - Math.random() );

                            } else {

                                if ( ! vt[ 4 ] ) {

                                    vt[ 4 ] = 1;
                                    data.up += 1;

                                }

                            }

                        }


                    }

                    // all down

                    if ( data.down === vl ) {

                        if ( data.delay === 0 ) {

                            data.direction = 1;
                            data.speed = 10;
                            data.down = 0;
                            data.delay = 10;

                            for ( i = 0; i < vl; i ++ ) {

                                vertices_tmp[ i ][ 3 ] = 0;

                            }

                        } else {

                            data.delay -= 1;

                        }


                    }

                    mesh.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

                }  
renderer.clear();
                composer.render( 0.01 );    
            }
```

I want to rotate that object which i have imported in scripts (i.e - txtS.json) using mouse .
How can i do that ? Please help me out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to use one of the controller that three.js give you?

[OrbitControl](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_orbit) for example.

The integration is fairly simple, you need to include the controller file

```
<script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Instantiate it in your init

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

And update in your animate function (before calling render)

```
controls.update();
```

Comment: And if you interesting only on rotation and want to disable zoom and pan, you can do it by setting: controls.noZoom = true, and controls.noPan = true.

Comment: Thanks it help me a lot . Is it possible with MousMove ? And one more thing i want to Create continius bubble particles running in background .

Comment: Warning: `OrbitControls` does **NOT** move the object (as asked) but instead, orbits the camera around a target. First line of the docs.